# Setting up Redis cache with Django

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I have a django project on an ubuntu EC2 node, that performs a computationally intensive long running process, that typically takes over 60 seconds. I need to cache the results. Never having worked with a cache before, I am following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/07/14/using-redis-as-django-session-store-and-cache-backend/ to use redis for this. In the article the author refers to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/ which contains the following:

```
  given a URL, try finding that page in the cache
  if the page is in the cache:
  return the cached page
else:
  generate the page
  save the generated page in the cache (for next time)
  return the generated page
```

This is the basic logic which I will need to implement in my django view. However , although I've read through the remainder of the cache docs, I'm still unclear on how to code this logic into my django view.

My current django view contains;

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):

# long running process started on request. Resulting html page should be cached

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

How do I code the above logic into my view?

Comment: Is it really the entire HTML page you want to cache, or just a particular item that is returned by your long-running process?

Comment: And if it is the full page, did you read on down that page for the [full explanation of how to cache an individual page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I did read that but I now realize I need something a little different than the standard cache, I'm going to delete this and ask a better question.